# RaisePropertyChanged() is not updating the value of a single button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been using MVVM with my WPF application for a while now, however I'm trying to keep a button disabled until such time as it can be enabled. No problem, I'll just make a bool in the ViewModel and tie it into that.

Bool:

```
    private bool m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton;
    public bool EnableLoadQuickStatsButton
    {
        get { return m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton; }
        set { m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EnableLoadQuickStatsButton"); }
    }
```

XAML Button:

```
                <Button Margin="5"
                        FontSize="14"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding EnableLoadQuickStatsButton}">
                    Load Quickstats
                </Button>
```

DataContext Declaration:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource MainScreenViewModel}
```

.gif of designer and example of the button being enabled/disabled by initial property value: http://i.imgur.com/lpVeEBd.gif

The button is enabled/disabled based on whatever that Property starts out as. However, changing the property does not enable/disable my button. Why is this? I don't seem to have any issues with any of my other controls and properties.

Edit:

**My class properly implements INotifyPropertyChanged, there are other properties that have their values bound to controls in my WPF application that work as expected.**

Edit2: A.gif of the application, showing other parts of it where DataBinding works: http://i.imgur.com/lIvzHv7.gif

Edit3: Output upon starting debugging:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=51180192) for Binding (hash=56315736)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.Button.IsEnabled (hash=23804398)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Found data context element: Button (hash=23804398) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Activate with root item MainScreenViewModel (hash=64564967)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192):   At level 0 - for MainScreenViewModel.EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): Replace item at level 0 with MainScreenViewModel (hash=64564967), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): GetValue at level 0 from MainScreenViewModel (hash=64564967) using RuntimePropertyInfo(EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest): 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=51180192): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
```

**Edit4:** Created a new project, and it works as expected, just doesn't on my current project for some reason.

Comment: What does your `RaisePropertyChanged` do? Does your class properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes it does, all other properties and controls work fine. Except this one, with no reason as to why.

Comment: Is set DataContext property of view correctly?

Comment: It is, I can enable/disable the button by setting the value of the property in design time. However I cannot enable/disable the button afterwards by changing the property. I pulled up another program of mine that has loads of enabled/disabled buttons and other elements that works fine just to test for sanities sake.

Comment: Please add data context declaration to your question

Comment: As an aside, it's usually preferable to bind buttons to an `ICommand` implementation.  Its enabled state will then be bound to the result of `ICommand.CanExecute`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. @VMaleev I added the line for the datacontext for the UserControl. I also added a .gif of me setting the data  binding as well as showing an example of how the button is enabled/disabled based on the initial value of the property.

Comment: First thing to do in such cases: add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the binding and watch the output window.

Comment: Try setting binding mode to TwoWay.

Comment: @Maxence did that and posted log!
NikhilV Just did, no change :(

Comment: @douglasg14b are you using a `Command` on that button that you haven't shown us?

Comment: I am not, the XAML posted is the entirety of the button.

Comment: You are setting the datacontext using `{StaticResource}`. Where is your viewmodel instance declared? Is it in a `Resource` in your XAML? Are you sure the instance of the viewmodel you are changing your property on is the one that is being set as the datacontext, or do you have some other instance of it (that you might have `new`'ed somewhere else?)

Comment: The DataContext is set in the UserControl, the ViewModel resource is declared in app.xaml. I am using the same Static data context. Actually the reason I'm using a static datacontext defined in App.xaml is to avoid instantiating other ViewModels while I am learning in other places.

Comment: You may want to make 100% sure (just to rule that out). Should be an easy test: wherever you are changing the bool property, make a  `object.ReferenceEquals(theButton.DataContext, myViewmodel);` and see if that's true (or just watch on the debugger the button's `DataContext` property and check if the bool has changed there). I'm saying this because this all should work, unless you have commands or otherwise have any behaviour or event that modifies the `IsEnabled` property or binding later, which you say you don't.

Comment: @douglasg14b, Do you bind IsEnabled for any another button and does it work? And please add button style code to your question

Comment: Did that! Test comes out positive. The buttons datacontext is an instance other than the one I am expecting to be using. Just to verify I decided to add a logger call to the constructor of my MainScreenViewodel and it is instantiated twice. Turns out I am instantiating and then applying a viewmodel to my MainWindow programatically in App.xaml.cs upon Startup. I have since fixed this, please post this as an answer. That is so simple.... wow. I'm rather embarrassed.

Comment: @douglasg14b posted it as answer with some extra tip just so I didn't make it really short. Glad you solved it.

Comment: Totally off topic, but how did you create those GIF-y screen plays? Those are awesome. I wanna do that with my Stackoverflow questions :D

Comment: @Laith I use LiceCap. It's a free screen recording tool that spits out a .gif It records at pretty low framerates though, so it's only good for things like what I posted.

Comment: @douglasg14b and that's exactly what I'd use it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, seems the ViewModel is being instantiated several times, and the one in the button's `DataContext` is not the same instance that was being changed.

A simple test proved it.

As for some extended tips... the idea behind using MVVM is separating the view from the model. I'd avoid having properties whose name imply "buttons" or any other visual element.

`EnableLoadQuickStatsButton` in the ViewModel should be called something like `AreQuickStatsReadyToBeLoaded` or something like that

Comment: Additionally the OP would be better off binding the button to a property that returns an ICommand.

Comment: @slugster indeed, and using `CanExecute` instead of setting `IsEnabled`

Comment: I will definitely try and do that!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code and it just worked well.

The code should be

`EnableLoadQuickStatsButton = AFunctionReturnsBool();`

when changing the property, Maybe you used

`m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton = AFunctionReturnsBool();`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Double checked, I also just created a new project and it works fine. I'm definitely changing `EnableLoadQuickStatsButton`. And just for insurance I have went ahead and called `RaisePropertyChanged` for every property in my viewmodel after changing the bools value. I have also made appropriate breakpoints and can verify the bool has been changed.

Comment: And make sure the container of the button is enabled?

Comment: By container, do you mean the panel it is in? It currently sits in a DockPanel that is enabled, yes.